# Error if Apache CFX is inluded directly in the project with maven

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I have got a very frustrating problem with Apache CFX.
My Stack is as follows:

- JakartaEE 9
- TomEE plume 9.0.0-M3
- jdk 11

I have an backend that provides REST Webservices threw JAX-RS
If I deploy my application everything is working just fine.

Now to my Problem, as I tried implementing File Uploads I noticed I would not be able to avoid
implementation specific feature to do it. I my case it was Apache cxf, as it is already the implementation tomee comes with. So I included the dependencies I needed with maven:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

That is in order to use the @Multipart annotation.
After that I get the following error:

```
 jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.    
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.handleClassCastException(ContextFinder.java:111)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:254)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JAXBContextFactory.newInstance(JAXBContextFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.getContext(JaxbJavaee.java:88)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:102)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:162)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.readBeans(ReadDescriptors.java:689)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.mergeBeansXml(DeploymentLoader.java:1190)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addBeansXmls(DeploymentLoader.java:1178)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:1094)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:818)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:230)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1198)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5082)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:658)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:47)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:177)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:272)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
09-Mar-2021 20:29:10.620 SCHWERWIEGEND [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.mergeBeansXml Unable to read beans.xml from: file:/A:/Workspaces/shop_backend/target/shop_backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/beans.xml
    org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Cannot unmarshall the beans.xml: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.    
        at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.readBeans(ReadDescriptors.java:694)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.mergeBeansXml(DeploymentLoader.java:1190)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addBeansXmls(DeploymentLoader.java:1178)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:1094)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:818)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:230)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1198)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5082)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:658)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:47)
        at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:177)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:272)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:221)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
        at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.    
        at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.handleClassCastException(ContextFinder.java:111)
        at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:254)
        at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
        at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
        at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
        at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JAXBContextFactory.newInstance(JAXBContextFactory.java:130)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.getContext(JaxbJavaee.java:88)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:102)
        at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.readBeans(ReadDescriptors.java:689)
        ... 70 more
jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/A:/Tomcat/shop_system_tomee/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.    
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.handleClassCastException(ContextFinder.java:111)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:254)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JAXBContextFactory.newInstance(JAXBContextFactory.java:130)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.getContext(JaxbJavaee.java:88)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:102)
    at org.apache.openejb.jee.JaxbJavaee.unmarshalJavaee(JaxbJavaee.java:162)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ReadDescriptors.readBeans(ReadDescriptors.java:689)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.mergeBeansXml(DeploymentLoader.java:1190)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addBeansXmls(DeploymentLoader.java:1178)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:1094)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.createWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:818)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:230)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1198)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5082)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWar(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:658)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.deployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.deployment.TomcatWebappDeployer.deploy(TomcatWebappDeployer.java:47)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.deploy(DeployerEjb.java:177)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:272)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I read a lot of stuff about this error online but nobody really seemed to know what to do.
If I remove the dependency everything works fine again.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are including all the dependencies again (so the container already has them, and you are including them in your WEB-INF/lib), while you probably just need to add the cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs dependency.
So the solution would be excluding all the transitive dependencies, like so:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>*</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Or declaring it as provided, as the container "provides" these dependencies (it won't include this dependency in the WEB-INF/lib, but you can still use them in your code):

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```